# Embed / Iframe on Google Streetview, disable click but keep the drag

Tags: google-street-view

This is a question [due an older post from Cesare](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241593/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-arrows-control-in-google-street-view).

In my case I want to disable click but keep the drag (so you can explore the 360-degree camera) in an **embedded (with Iframe) map** on Streetview.

Here is the [map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/241593/how-to-programmatically-enable-disable-arrows-control-in-google-street-view) I am trying to embed and is from the International Space Station.

I tried with Cesare solution (JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimgk1984/zes7abua/)) but (maybe because is the International space station and there are some legal rights) it shows a black screen with the note: Image may be subject to copyright. Therefore now I am trying with iframe. Here is my [code on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimgk1984/8tnxo3as/137/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Street View controls</title>
   <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="map-container">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!4v1518736193836!6m8!1m7!1szChzPIAn4RIAAAQvxgbyEg!2m2!1d29.56028532748453!2d-95.08539144618427!3f213.12!4f0.18000000000000682!5f0.7820865974627469" style="margin-top:-100px" width="100%" height="1000" frameborder="0"allowfullscreen >
   </iframe>
        <style>
        .map-container {
        </style>
  </body>
</html>
```